# Svcutil does not generate async methods or GetEndpointAddress for an asmx

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

I cannot get the svcutil to generate code like the connected services does. Cannot generate both async and sync and the getendpointAddress method

```
svcutil.exe /out:"C:\MyDir\reference.cs" /async /n:*,MyNamespace http://whatever.com/aa.asmx
```

what Am I missing?

Comment: You can try adding the `wsdl` in the end of the command like this: `svcutil.exe http://whatever.com/aa.asmx?WSDL`. Or get more error logs to locate the problem.

Comment: I did no difference

Comment: Is there any progress? Any information when the error occured?